# Continuous maps between open/closed topological subspaces give a continuous map between topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, topological-groups

Let $A,B$ be topological spaces and $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ a map.
Let $A',A''\subseteq A$ with $A=A'\cup A''$ and the maps $\phi|_{A'}:A'\rightarrow B$ en $\phi|_{A''}:A''\rightarrow B$ are continuous.

> How do I prove that $\phi$ is continuous if
>   1. $A',A''$ are open?
>   2. $A',A''$ are closed?

What I have done:
I know that for $\phi$ to be continuous we must have that $\phi^{-1}B\in\mathcal{T_A}$, but I'm not sure what to do with the information that is given.

Comment: You must use the definition to prove continuity: for any open set $U$ in $B$, $\phi^{-1}(U)$ should be open (not just when $U=B$).

Comment: @MichaelBurr But if $A'$ is open in $A$, does that mean that $\phi|_{A'}(A)$ is open in $B$?

Comment: Usually not, perhaps $\phi$ is a constant map, then the image is not open in $B$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Then how can I use your first comment to prove continuity of $\phi$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $U$ be an open set in $B$.

In the case where $A'$ and $A''$ are open (each of the following statements requires proof):

1) 
$$\phi^{-1}U=\phi|_{A'}^{-1}(U)\cup\phi|_{A''}^{-1}(U)
$$

2) Since $\phi|_{A'}$ and $\phi|_{A''}$ are continuous (and assuming they are given the subspace topology), there are open sets $V'$ and $V''$ in $A$ so that
$$
\phi|_{A'}^{-1}(U)=V'\cap A'
$$
and
$$
\phi|_{A''}^{-1}(U)=V''\cap A''
$$

3) Then, $\phi^{-1}U=(V'\cap A')\cup (V''\cap A'')$, which is a finite union/intersection of open sets (and therefore is open).

For the case where $A'$ and $A''$ are closed, use the fact that the preimage of a closed set is closed is another definition of continuity.

Comment: And for "closed" the proof is the same way, except you replace the word 'open' by 'closed', right?

Comment: Not quite, because then you are intersecting closed sets and open sets.

Comment: So then I would get that $\phi|_{A'}^{-1}(U)$ and $\phi|_{A''}^{-1}(U)$ are closed if $U$ is closed?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is continuous iff the preimage of a closed set is closed.

Comment: And then $\phi^{-1}(U)=\phi|_{A'}^{-1}(U)\cup\phi|_{A''}^{-1}(U)$ is closed, since it is a finite union of closed sets?

Comment: Yes, that is true (it might be helpful for you to review the axioms of a topology so that you become more comfortable with them).

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ be an open subset of $B$. Since $\phi_{A'}$ and $\phi_{A''}$ are continuous, $\phi_{A'}^{-1}(U)$ and $\phi_{A''}^{-1}(U)$ are open.
By definition $\phi_{A'}^{-1}(U) = \{x \in A' \mid \phi(x) \in U\}$ and
$\phi_{A''}^{-1}(U) = \{x \in A'' \mid \phi(x) \in U\}$. It follows that
$$
\phi_{A'}^{-1}(U) \cup \phi_{A''}^{-1}(U) = \{x \in A' \cup A'' \mid \phi(x) \in U\} = \phi^{-1}(U)
$$
and thus $\phi^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that $A'$ and $A''$ are open and show that $\phi$ is continuous. Let $U\subset B$ an open set of $B$. We have to show that $\phi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A$.

$\phi|_{A'}^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A'$, as $\phi|_{A'}$ is continuous. This means, using induced topology, that there exists $O_1$ open in $A$ such that $\phi|_{A'}^{-1}(U)=A'\cap O_1$.

We also have, for the same reasons, $\phi|_{A''}^{-1}(U)=A'\cap O_2$ with $O_2$ open in $A''$.

Thus, $\phi^{-1}(U)=\phi|_{A'}^{-1}(U)\cup \phi|_{A''}^{-1}(U)=(A'\cap O_1)\cup (A''\cap O_2)$.

If $A'$ and $A''$ are open, then $A'\cap O_1$ and $A''\cap O_2$ are open and $\phi^{-1}(U)$ too.

You can do the same kind of proof in the case where $A'$ and $A''$ are closed.